# Probability of mother and children have thalassemia

Tags: probability

> There are $25$ % chance that mother is thalassemia minor.If she is a minor, Then each son has again a $25$ % of having thalassemia independently.If the mother is not thalassemia minor,Then the son will not have this disease.

> $(1)$ Given that mother has $3$ sons without the disease. Then what is the probability that mother was a thalassemia minor.

> $(2)$ Given that mother has $3$ sons without the disease. Then what is the probability that $4$th son, if born, he will have thalassemia.

What i try :: let $A$ be the event that mother has thalassemia.

And $E_{1},E_{2},E_{3},E_{4}$ be $4$ events such that each children has thalassemia independently.

So $P(A)=1/4$ and $P(\bar{A})=3/4$

And $P(E_{1})=P(E_{2})=P(E_{3})=P(E_{4})=1/4$

For $(1)$ part:
$$P\bigg(\frac{A}{E_{1}\cap E_{2} \cap E_{3}}\bigg)=\frac{P(A \cap E_{1} \cap E_{2} \cap E_{3})}{P(E_{1} \cap E_{2} \cap E_{3})}$$

Did not understand How do I solve it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Why state a 17-letter disease name that is irrelevant... several times?  Would your problem differ if the disease were pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis?  Would it matter that perhaps it could be treated with METHIONYLTHREONYLTHREONYGLUTAMINYLARGINYL … ISOLEUCINE?

Comment: @Gae.S.:  "Cancer" has six letters, "brain" stands for where the cancer is found.  So?

Comment: I was counting the space, but so what.  Ummm... "ursa major," "ursa minor," and so on are the unified names for constellations, as a related example.  As you can see from here (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) bad question askers (such as jacky) put in useless, irrelevant specific details.  It shows they don't see to the core of a question, will "confuse" automatic search algorithms on this site.  The question includes:  "If she is a minor."  What does the mother being younger than 18 have to do with anything.  Oh... (you say)... it is the disease!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Bayes' law.

$$\Pr(A\vert E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)=\tfrac{\Pr(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3 \vert A)P(A)}{P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)}$$

Now, $\Pr(E_i\vert A)=0.25$ and

$$P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)=P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3\vert A)\Pr(A)+P(E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3\vert \bar{A})\Pr(\bar{A})=0.25^3\cdot 0.25 + 1^3 \cdot 0.75$$

Finally, $\Pr(A\vert E_1\cap E_2 \cap E_3)=\tfrac{0.25^3\cdot 0.25}{0.25^3\cdot 0.25+0.75}=0.0052$

For the second question, you can use the same method. The posterior probability that she has it is $0.0052$ so the probability that the fourth child will be sick is $0.0052\cdot 0.25$